# If-then statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing two sets of if-else statements which are very similar. They basically compare three drop down menus and ensure that the user has not put down two matching preferences. For example:

```
cbo_fac1 - Kitchen    
cbo_fac2 - Kitchen   
cbo_fac3 - Lounge
```

This would return an error message because **cbo_fac1** and **cbo_fac2** match up. But there is a special case scenario I'm struggling to implement. One of the drop down cases is *No preference*.

```
cbo_fac1 - Kitchen    
cbo_fac2 - No preference
cbo_fac3 - No preference

cbo_fac1 - No preference    
cbo_fac2 - No preference
cbo_fac3 - No preference
```

With any scenario *No preference* selection is allowed to match. How do I go about implementing this? Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
If cbo_fac1.Value = cbo_fac2.Value Then
    MsgBox ("Facilities preference 1 and facilities preference 2 cannot be the same. Please select another option for facilities preference 2, if you have none then select 'No preference'")
    Exit Sub
End If

If cbo_fac1.Value = cbo_fac3.Value Then
    MsgBox ("Facilities preference 1 and facilities preference 3 cannot be the same. Please select another option for facilities preference 3, if you have none then select 'No preference'")
    Exit Sub
End If

If cbo_fac2.Value = cbo_fac3.Value Then
    MsgBox ("Facilities preference 2 and facilities preference 3 cannot be the same. Please select another option for facilities preference 3, if you have none then select 'No preference'")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write it as one giant if statement, this should do:

```
If (cbo_fac1.Value <> cbo_fac2.Value Or cbo_fac1.Value = "No Preference") And _
   (cbo_fac2.Value <> cbo_fac3.Value Or cbo_fac2.Value = "No Preference") And _
   (cbo_fac1.Value <> cbo_fac3.Value Or cbo_fac3.Value = "No Preference") Then
     'Input is fine
else
     exit sub

End If
```

Edit:

Just because here's the reverse way, with a possible msgbox:

```
If (cbo_fac1.value = cbo_fac2.value AND cbo_fac1.value <> "No Preference") OR _
   (cbo_fac2.value = cbo_fac3.value AND cbo_fac2.value <> "No Preference") OR _
   (cbo_fac1.value = cbo_fac3.value AND cbo_fac3.value <> "No Preference") then

   Msgbox "No two facilities can be the same. Please select another option " & _
          "for facilities preference, if you have none then select 'No preference'"
   exit sub
else
   'input is fine
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Check something like

```
If cbo_fac1.Value = cbo_fac2.Value and cbo_fac1.Value <> "No Preference" and cbo_fac2.Value <> "No Preference" Then
    MsgBox ("Facilities preference 1 and facilities preference 2 cannot be the same. Please select another option for facilities preference 2, if you have none then select 'No preference'")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Do the same check for other 2 IF conditions.

### UPDATE:

There is another way, by writing a function

Below is the sample function.

```
Sub PreferenceCheck(var1 As String, var2 As String)
    If var1 = "No Preference" Or var2 = "No Preference" Then
        tempVar = true
    End If
    If Not tempVar Then
        If var1=var2 Then
            MsgBox ("Facilities "&var1&" and facilities "&var2&" cannot be the same. Please select another option for facilities preference, if you have none then select 'No preference'")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Calling this function for 3 combinations

```
PreferenceCheck(cbo_fac1.Value, cbo_fac2.Value)
PreferenceCheck(cbo_fac2.Value, cbo_fac3.Value)
PreferenceCheck(cbo_fac1.Value, cbo_fac3.Value)
```

Comment: Is there a way to merge all three if conditions?

Comment: @methuselah: Yes, you can achieve this by writing a function. Refer my sample function which I have updated in my answer.

Comment: This will need to be re-written slightly if you want it to exit sub, because right now there is no way for the code to know if the PreferenceCheck passed or not. I'd recommend changing the sub to a function that returns a boolean and then placing all of the preferencechecks in an if separated with ANDs.